# Обзвон абонентов с посощью IVR Asterisk

Tags: asterisk, elastix

Необходимо выполнить обзвон абонентов роботом для сбора информации.

---

У астериска есть решение для автообзвона, но сновная проблема в том что при звонке с астера абоненту может ответить автоответчик или пользователь может ничего не ввести или пользователь может выбрать пункт "перезвонить позже" и в этом случае астер всеравно поставит статуc звонка Completed и штатная система автообзвона завершит работу с номером.

---

Можно ли как то из диалплана зафейлить статус звонка чтобы астериск своими средствами перезвонил позже?

Поставил для пробы Elastix с модулем CAll Center, но мне кажеться обзвон там можно выполнить только с помощью живых операторов... Или все же можно сделать кампанию обзвона роботами?

Answer (score 1):

На мой взгляд не самая лучшая идея использовать робота для сбора информации. Вам самим приятно слушать при входящем "*подождите, происходит соединение с оператором...*" или тп.? Чувствуется какое-то неуважение. Я обычно сразу же кладу трубку. На мой взгляд все эти автообзвоны полезны для автоинформирования, не более (например, как в такси: "Вас ожидает ..."). Лучше живого оператора посадить на прозвон, который и от автоответчиков отобьется и собеседника сможет на разговор настроить.

> Можно ли как то из диалплана зафейлить статус звонка чтобы астериск
>   своими средствами перезвонил позже?

По статусу звонка ${DIALSTATUS} можно определить, был ли отвечен звонок (автоответчиком или человеком).

По выбору пункта в голосовом меню типа "Хотите, чтобы мы перезвонили позже - нажмите 1" можно запланировать звонок на более позднее время.

В любом лучае, лучше написать свой кусок диалплана. Мало-ли потом какие идеи у руководства возникнут, можно будет реализовать.

> Поставил для пробы Elastix с модулем CAll Center, но мне кажеться
>   обзвон там можно выполнить только с помощью живых операторов... Или
>   все же можно сделать кампанию обзвона роботами?

К сожалению дел с Elastix не имею, но думаю можно настройками отправить отвеченный звонок на нужный кусок диалплана. А там уже реализуйте обработку как захочется.

Comment: Сбор информации проиходит с клиентов которые уже зарегистрировались, они ждут этого звонка потому трубку ложить не будут.

> можно запланировать звонок на более позднее время.
Как это сделать? Тачить колфайл и перемещать его поять в папку?

Comment: Ну, да. При выборе пункта формируете нужный колфайл, задаете ему нужную дату создания (например, текущее время + 2 часа) и перемещаете в папку. Астериск сам по времени создания файла перезвонит в указанное время.